# C# BinarySearch breaks when inheriting from something that implements IComparable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, sorting, interface

In .NET the BinarySearch algorithm (in Lists, Arrays, etc.) appears to fail if the items you are trying to search inherit from an IComparable instead of implementing it directly:

```
List<B> foo = new List<B>(); // B inherits from A, which implements IComparable<A>
foo.Add(new B());
foo.BinarySearch(new B());   // InvalidOperationException, "Failed to compare two elements in the array."
```

Where:

```
public abstract class A : IComparable<A>
{
    public int x;

    public int CompareTo(A other)
    {
        return x.CompareTo(other.x);
    }
}

public class B : A {}
```

Is there a way around this? Implementing CompareTo(B other) in class B doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This code builds a runs just fine on my C# compiler

Comment: @Stewart - you are probably using C# 4.

Comment: @Kobi - whoops, quite right. I forgot this had changed and the question doesn't mention a version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation makes this quite clear:

> checks whether type T implements the IComparable generic interface and uses that implementation, if available. If not, Comparer.Default  checks whether type T implements the IComparable  interface. If type T does not implement either interface, Comparer.Default  throws an InvalidOperationException.

So, a simple solution is to implement the non-generic interface `IComparable`.
Adding `CompareTo(B other)` **will** work for you, as long as you also implement `IComparable<B>` - you probably forgot that bit.

An interesting solution is to compile the code using C# 4, where it runs without any errors. C# 4 introduces Generic Covariance: `public interface IComparable<in T>` vs `public interface IComparable<T>`, and the posted code works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Right, so the problem is it tries to see if `class B` implements `IComparable<B>`, which it doesn't, because it actually implements `IComparable<A>`, then tries `IComparable` then gives up. As Kobi pointed out, implementing non-generic `IComparable` will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answers are correct for .net versions prior to 4.0, it's worth noting that .Net 4.0 defines IComparable<T> covariantly, which means that if class implements IComparable<BaseType> but does not explicitly implement IComparable<DerivedType>, the implementation if IComparable<BaseType> will be regarded as an implementation if IComparable<DerivedType>.

Note that this does not apply to IEquatable<T>, but since derivable types shouldn't implement IEquatable<T> anyway, that shouldn't be a problem.

Note also that unlike IEquatable<T> which is logically bound to implement semantics very similar to Object.Equals (since objects whose GetHashCode implementations return unequal must compare unequal), there are a number of cases where IComparable<BaseType> should logically return equal even though IComparable<DerivedType> should compare unequal (in such cases, a derived type should typically implement IComparable<DerivedType> but not reimplement IComparable<BaseType>.  Note that if IComparable<T>.Compare returns zero, that does not imply that the objects are *equal*, but merely that neither one definitively ranks above the other.